# Generating outcomes of a Laplacian Random variable

Tags: matlab, variables, random

I would like to get some help on stemming a function of outcomes and trials while my given data are: **X=sqrt(1/2)*ln(1/0.01)** where **X** is a **random variable**.I want to represent outcomes for 50 trials with the **stem** function of Matlab but I don't know how...**It's in the 10th chapter of Steven Kay's Book Intuitive Probability and Random Processes Using MATLAB** The result should look like this : [The Diagramm http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/1733/exampledi.jpg](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/1733/exampledi.jpg)
any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you found the [`stem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html) plot function? Is your question about plotting or about random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this (you'll need to supply your own data):

```
figure
x = 0:0.2:2*pi;
y = cos(x);
stem(x,y,'k.')
grid on
```